# Avoid to load default WP styles in login screen

Tags: login, css, wp-enqueue-style, wp-login-form, wp-register-style

Is there some way to avoid the load of default WordPress styles in login screen to only load my custom stylesheets?

Actually I'm using this code:

```
function login_styles() {
    // Sets the styles if is the current theme
    if (get_stylesheet_directory() == get_template_directory()) {
        // Prints link to stylesheed login.css
        wp_register_style(...);
        wp_enqueue_style(...);
    }
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_styles' );
```

It works well but WordPress first loads its styles. I want to exclude that files from this screen.

Comment: I have post a query about this on WP Support forum.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/avot-to-print-default-wp-styles-in-wp-loginphp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `wp_deregister_style( 'login' )` to remove the login styles will still result in a 404'd request for the login CSS file. However, if you re-register the login style after deregistering it you can prevent the unwanted request.

```
add_action( 'login_init', function() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'login' );
    wp_register_style( 'login' );
} );
```

This will leave you with a completely unstyled `wp-login.php` page. To restyle it you could instead register your own CSS file under the `login` handle.

This might be more helpful than messing with the `style_loader_tag` filter.

---

**Update:**

`login_enqueue_scripts` is a more appropriate action and dequeuing doesn't result in a 404.

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'login' );
} );
```

Comment: wp_register_style( 'login',false );

to remove error that comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Following the lead of a G.M. comment in a deleted answer, where he points out that the login styles are printed with `wp_admin_css()` <sup>**`*`**</sup>, I've found a filter that does the job, `style_loader_tag`. <strike>But further tests show that `wp_deregister_style` is enough</strike>.

Feedback and further-further tests reveal that deregistering the style produces a 404 for `wp-admin.css`, so back to the loader tag:

```
add_action( 'login_init', function() 
{
    # Produces a 404 for the style
    // wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' );

    # The following is a filter in /wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php
    # Completely cleans up the <head> of enqueues
    add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', '__return_null' );
});
```

<sub>**`*`** There's even a filter inside this function, but seems that it doesn't catch registered styles.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for te answer. But that code only deregisters the styles, the CSS file stills being requested in the HTML with a 404 response, so the page is trying to load the styles.

Comment: I'm trying to use this function `wp_dequeue_style()` with the code you have provided to avoid WordPress prints that styles in the web, but doesn't seem to do nothing.

Comment: I didn't notice the 404 for deregister style, but the second option, `style_loader_tag` works without any glitch.

Comment: I get a look to the WordPress _wp-login.php_ code and found the nexy code:
`wp_admin_css( 'wp-admin', true );
wp_admin_css( 'colors-fresh', true );`
That function `wp_admin_css()` with the 2th arg to `TRUE` prints the registered styles without enqueuing them.

Comment: @AlbertFM, answer updated, seems that you didn't try the second option...

Comment: Yes, I tried `add_action( 'login_init', function() { add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', '__return_null' ); });` and that not prints my styles too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to remove the styles from the login screen:

```
function login_styles_reset( $style ) {
    if ( strpos( $style, 'wp-admin-css') !== FALSE ) {
        $style = NULL;
    } elseif ( strpos( $style, 'colors-fresh-css') !== FALSE ) {
        $style = NULL;
    }
    return $style;
}

function custom_login_styles() {
    add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'login_styles_reset' );

    // Code for the new login styles
}
add_action( 'login_init', 'custom_login_styles');
```

Hope that helps someone else.